# Convert the date to device timezone using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter, nscalendar

I am getting a list of dates as a service response, where I show a calendar where these dates are marked with dots (example that date has an event.). The response gives the date with GMT as

```
[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "filled_date": "2019-11-21T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "filled_date": "2019-11-26T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "filled_date": "2019-11-28T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
]
```

How ever when using this at other timezone, it is showing the previous or next dates as marked based on the timezone. for example 2019 nov 21 should be marked as the dot for the event for that day, however in the US time Zone, this is 2019 nov 20.

How do I show this date as 21st Nov,2019 irrespective of any timezone.

Comment: You just need to set your date formatter timezone to GMT when displaying the date to the user

Answer (score -1):

You want your data formatter to use the GMT time zone, and not the user's device time zone.  Something like this:

```
lazy var dmyFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let dmyFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dmyFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    dmyFormatter.dateStyle = .long
    return dmyFormatter
}()
```